# How to swap from gpu to a cpu only?

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

Hi I was wondering how can run a machine learning code onto my CPU instead of a GPU?

I have tried making the GPU false on the setting file but it hasn't been able to fix it.

### global settings

```
GPU = False                                                                 # running on GPU is highly suggested
CLEAN = False                                                                # set to "True" if you want to clean the temporary large files after generating result
APP = "classification"                                                       # Do not change! mode choide: "classification", "imagecap", "vqa". Currently "imagecap" and "vqa" are not supported.
CATAGORIES = ["object", "part"]                                              # Do not change! concept categories that are chosen to detect: "object", "part", "scene", "material", "texture", "color"
map_location='cpu'

CAM_THRESHOLD = 0.5                                                          # the threshold used for CAM visualization
FONT_PATH = "components/font.ttc"                                            # font file path
FONT_SIZE = 26                                                               # font size
SEG_RESOLUTION = 7                                                           # the resolution of cam map
BASIS_NUM = 7
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    model = loadmodel()
  File "/home/joshuayun/Desktop/IBD/loader/model_loader.py", line 44, in loadmodel
    checkpoint = torch.load(settings.MODEL_FILE)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 537, in persistent_load
    deserialized_objects[root_key] = restore_location(obj, location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 119, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 95, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 79, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU.
```

Comment: Please do *not* use both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7` tags in the same question - it does not make any sense.

Comment: Have you tried `torch.cuda.set_device('cpu')` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a model extended from `nn.Module` you can move your entire model to CPU or GPU doing this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
model.to(device)
# or
device = torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)
```

If you'd like to move just a Tensor:

```
x = torch.Tensor(10).cuda()
# or
x = torch.Tensor(10).cpu()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you are getting the above error at code `model = loadmodel()`. I don't have an idea what you are doing inside `loadmodel()`, but you can try below points:

- Set `defaults.device` to `cpu`. To be completely sure, add a `torch.cuda.set_device('cpu')`
- Change `torch.load(model_weights)` to `torch.load(model_weights, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))`

Answer (score 0):

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'