# Plotting a graph using pickle file saved on gpu using pytorch

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, pickle

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.title('train loss')
plt.xlabel('')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.plot(torch.load('./t_accli2.pickle', map_location = 'cpu'))
plt.savefig('./train_acc')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot the above graph. and get the following error.
My model is trained on a GPU and the plotting is also being done on the GPU. Still I receive the following error. I have saved the file using pickle.dump. It is a pickle file of accuracies and not the saved model.

```
plt.plot(torch.load('./t_accli2.pickle', map_location = 'cpu'))
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 692, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/storage.py", line 134, in _load_from_bytes
    return torch.load(io.BytesIO(b))
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 529, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 702, in _legacy_load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 665, in persistent_load
    deserialized_objects[root_key] = restore_location(obj, location)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 156, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 132, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)
  File "/home/enterprise.internal.city.ac.uk/adbb083/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 116, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

Comment: does this helps:https://stackoverflow.com/a/56758399/6660373?

Comment: Also as mentioned in the error: `map_location=torch.device('cpu')` not `map_location='cpu'`